# PHP Symfony 2 / Payum Bundle / Installing wiseape/sofort-ueberweisung

Tags: php, symfony, payum

Im facing issues installing the wiseape/sofort-ueberweisung gateway for the payum bundle. I can see it's a version dependency issue on payum core but can't figure out how to solve it.

My installed payum core has version 1.1 and wiseape/sofort-ueberweisung only requires 0.12.0 so I'm lost here as it also tells me to not install a core version of 0.12.x-dev?

This is the package: https://github.com/wiseape/payum-sofortuberweisung

This is the command I run:

**sudo php composer.phar require "wiseape/payum-sofortuberweisung"**

This is the result:

```
Using version ^1.1 for wiseape/payum-sofortuberweisung
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - wiseape/payum-sofortuberweisung 1.x-dev requires payum/core ~0.12.0 -> satisfiable by payum/core[0.12.x-dev].
    - wiseape/payum-sofortuberweisung v1.1.0 requires payum/core ~0.12.0 -> satisfiable by payum/core[0.12.x-dev].
    - wiseape/payum-sofortuberweisung v1.1.1 requires payum/core ~0.12.0 -> satisfiable by payum/core[0.12.x-dev].
    - wiseape/payum-sofortuberweisung v1.1.2 requires payum/core ~0.12.0 -> satisfiable by payum/core[0.12.x-dev].
    - wiseape/payum-sofortuberweisung v1.1.3 requires payum/core ~0.12.0 -> satisfiable by payum/core[0.12.x-dev].
    - wiseape/payum-sofortuberweisung v1.1.4 requires payum/core ~0.12.0 -> satisfiable by payum/core[0.12.x-dev].
    - wiseape/payum-sofortuberweisung v1.1.5 requires payum/core ~0.12.0 -> satisfiable by payum/core[0.12.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install payum/core 0.12.x-dev
    - Installation request for wiseape/payum-sofortuberweisung ^1.1 -> satisfiable by wiseape/payum-sofortuberweisung[1.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.1.1, v1.1.2, v1.1.3, v1.1.4, v1.1.5].
```

This is my composer.json

```
{
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"name": "ubuntu/api",
"license": "proprietary",
"type": "project",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/AppKernel.php"
    ]
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*@dev",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0@dev",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "snc/redis-bundle": "1.1.8",
    "predis/predis": "0.8.*",
    "payum/payum-bundle": "*@stable",
    "psliwa/pdf-bundle": "^1.0",
    "tfox/mpdf-port-bundle": "^1.3",
    "payum/offline": "*@stable",
    "payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp": "^1.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.1",
    "payum/core": "^1.1",
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It looks like this package is rather outdated (its last commit was made nearly one year ago). Is there no alternative package your can use for your use case?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer the library you want to use require pretty old payum core. There are four ways to go:

1. You can downgrade payum core version. In this case you can lost bug fixes, and feature improvements made in Payum.
2. Upgrade the library wiseape/sofort-ueberweisung up to 1.0 version. Upgrade notes may help you here a lot: https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/UPGRADE.md
3. There is an alternative extension https://github.com/invit/payum-sofortueberweisung which works in production, though it requrie payum version 0.15. Should be easier to upgrade from it to 1.0.
4. Also I started adding the sofort extension right into payum https://github.com/Payum/Payum/pull/447. The PR based on init's work. There are some things to finish up and test. Unfortunately I dont give you any ETA.